# Why does "heroku run python manage.py send_queued_mail" work from command line but not when in a clock.py file for Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, apscheduler

My clock.py below. I can use `heroku run python manage.py send_queued_mail` all day long but including `run python manage.py send_queued_mail` in a clock.py file causes a syntax error.

clock.py:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(minutes=1)
def timed_job():
    python manage.py send_queued_mail

sched.start()

while True:
    pass
```

Heroku error message (from log):

```
2014-01-24T01:31:47.256648+00:00 app[clock.1]:   File "clock.py", line 7
2014-01-24T01:31:47.256648+00:00 app[clock.1]:     run python manage.py send_queued_mail
2014-01-24T01:31:47.256648+00:00 app[clock.1]:              ^
2014-01-24T01:31:47.256648+00:00 app[clock.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT:
`management.call_command('send_queued_mail')` works from the python shell on heroku, but fails with a "command not found" error when I run it from the clock.py file. I can clearly see send_queued_email.py file where it is supposed to be. And if I run `python manage.py help` I can see 1send_queued_email` as an available command. Somehow running the command from clock.py is causing heroku to not fond the command.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
python manage.py send_queued_mail
```

is not valid Python code.

You can call a management command programmatically using [`django.core.management.call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code):

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('send_queued_mail')
```

Comment: Thanks. That at least didn't crash my Heroku worker. But I still get an error as follows: 2014-01-24T02:20:31.834713+00:00 app[clock.1]: No handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"

Comment: I added "from django.core.management import call_command
import logging" but I still get an error: CommandError: Unknown command: 'send_queued_mail'

Comment: @user2916527: Is `send_queued_mail` a valid management command? Does it work when you run it from the command line?

Comment: Yes - As I said in my EDIT (posted before your answer) `send_queued_mail` works from my local machine via `heroku run manage.py send_queued_mail`. And, again noted above, I see `send_queued_mail` as an available command if I type `heroku run manage.py help` on my local machine to show all the available manage.py commands for my app on heroku. The heroku support team is looking at it as we speak. I will post their answer when it comes.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. When calling my command from a python file, I needed to explicitly set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `mysite.settings`. Below is the final file for anyone else who ever decides they want to schedule async email sends from a Django app on Heroku with greater frequency than the once-every-5-minutes supported by the Heroku Scheduler add-on.

```
# clock.py

import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'anonqaproject.settings'

from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from post_office import utils

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(minutes=1)
def timed_job():
    utils.send_queued_mail()

sched.start()

while True:
    pass
```